# What is the time complexity of triple nested for loops of the following?

Tags: algorithm, for-loop, nested

I have some problems with time complexity determination. Please help me to find out the time complexity of the following problem in detail.

```
for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    for(j=1;j<=m;j++)
        for(k=1;k<=p;k++)
            print(arr[i][j][k]);
```

Comment: Please explain it for me. How can i write it as an assignment for my versity.

Comment: our teacher explain every algorithms time complexity in the form of 2n+1, n+3 line by line. Please explain it for me in such a way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the time complexity of a nested loop you need to understand how often every loop executes its body.

In your example `for(i=1;i<=n;i++)` is a loop running its body `n` times.

`for(j=1;j<=m;j++)` will run its body `m` times and `for(k=1;k<=p;k++)` will run its body `p` times.

Since the two inner loops will run each per iteration of their respective outer loop, you can make the following statements.

1. The first loop will run the second loop `n` times
2. The second loop will run the third loop `m` times, thus the third loop will run `n*m` times
3. The third loop will run the print statement `p` times, thus the print statement is run `n*m*p` times.

Thus, the time complexity of this code is `ϴ(n*m*p)`.

In general, when talking about nested loops the time complexity of the code will always be in terms of the loop conditions. There are indeed special cases, like dependent loop conditions or loops containing code with `break` statements for a certainly occurring condition.

Now here I would like to mention that what we actually count here are the comparisons made by the `for` loops, not really how often the `print` statement is executed. Still, counting with the `print` statement and the loop bodies as a base makes it easier and the time complexity is still the same.